# Minor bug on review page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

On Chrome 9.0.597.84 on Windows Vista (don't ask...) on the [**review**](https://apple.stackexchange.com/review) page, the line separator (declared in `.question-summary`) is too long:

[image: apple stackexchange review]

The width parameter is not used. Probably because of the `width: 940px!important;` line in `.review-page #questions .question-summary`

It happens on Firefox 3.6.13 too.

Comment: this is being fixed. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment.